# Executing jmx file through jmeter in IBM cloud. every time result showing 100% error with same exception

Tags: java, sockets, ssh, jmeter, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

This is working fine in my local. Failing in IBM cloud. Error as below...
Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException/Non HTTP response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake

I have tried to add java certificate through console as

sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java

sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java

I got the error below

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470_27sr2fp10ifix-20150313_01(SR2 
FP10+IV70681))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.7, JRE 1.7.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 
20141215_227395 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_SR2_20141215_1631_B227395
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20141003_74587.07
GC   - R27_Java727_SR2_20141215_1631_B227395_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20141215_227395)
JCL - 20141217_01 based on Oracle jdk7u75-b12
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove ca-certificates-java which isn't 
installed
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package ca-certificates-java is not available, but is referred to by another 
package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Comment: Looks like you can't even get a connection to work. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly in case you are interest in more specific answers.

Comment: Information updated with more details

Comment: That message is very clear : there is no package of that name. Where did you get the idea that there is such a package? What makes you think the issue is based on certificates?